# атакуют на wampserver дома

Tags: wamp-server

вот access.log файл:

```
45.119.127.148 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:25 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
45.119.127.148 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:25 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
117.63.78.109 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:25 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
112.213.117.28 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:25 +0500] "POST /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
103.40.102.202 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:25 +0500] "POST /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
103.200.29.12 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:26 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
118.107.181.54 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:26 +0500] "POST /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
103.73.160.67 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:26 +0500] "POST /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
202.181.24.139 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:27 +0500] "POST /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
43.248.8.242 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:27 +0500] "POST /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
203.160.52.251 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:27 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
117.90.1.102 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:28 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
222.185.23.144 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:29 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
45.114.11.111 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:29 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
121.231.226.250 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:30 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
202.181.24.154 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:31 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
45.127.97.89 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:31 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
45.114.11.177 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:31 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
121.231.155.33 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:34 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
121.231.154.97 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:34 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
103.212.33.149 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:35 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
117.63.78.179 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:35 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
117.63.78.239 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:36 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
150.129.81.125 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:37 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
45.125.12.132 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:37 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
114.226.135.69 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:37 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
121.127.249.74 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:38 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
121.127.249.74 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:38 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
45.125.13.203 - - [10/Jan/2019:12:17:39 +0500] "GET /index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning HTTP/1.1" 200 20
```

Занимал процессор. Я отключиль это меню. Это был "связаться с нами". 
и еще в index.php файле добавил код:

```
if ($linkk == "/index.php/en/my-sp-page-2/biz-bilan-bo-laning"){
    echo "don't attack, ";
    usleep(50*1000000);
    echo "please";
    die;
}
```

Не понимаю зачем они отправят один и те же запрос на эту ссылку. Мои меры работают пока они не начнут отправить запрос на другие ссылки в моем сайте. Что мне делать?

Comment: Ну "зачем" вам никто не скажет. в интернете такое постоянно происходит. Самым правильным было бы на любую не существующую ссылку отвечать ошибкой 404, при этом конечно выполнив минимум работы на своей стороне, т.е. проверить недопустимость ссылки как можно раньше

Comment: А если они начнут отправить запрос на существующий ссылку которое я не могу отключить.

Comment: Это ваш личный сервер для разработки? Тогда настройте файрвол/роутер и не парьтесь. Выставили в интернет? ... странное решение, WAMP + домашний комп. жаль сто рублей на хостинг? `echo "don't attack, "; usleep(50*1000000); echo "please";` - уверен, что вы специально не настраивали ни веб-сервер, ни PHP, и то, что ожидаете не получите. PHP кеширует отправляемые данные в буфер, и выплюнет все разом. Веб-сервер также может это делать.

Comment: Если ссылки реальные, то тогда надо смотреть заголовки этих запросов, смотреть, может они чем то отличаются от реальных. Кстати, usleep вы только свой сервер нагружаете. т.е. процессор конечно свободен, но обработчик php занят и не может в это время обрабатывать другие запросы. А количество обработчиков обычно ограничено. Так что лучше сразу отдавать 404 и завершаться. Возвращать ошибку важно. некоторые боты все таки чуть чуть умные и коды ошибок смотрят и перестанут к вам стучатся если получат 404.

Comment: Если и это все не помогает, тогда потребуется более сложный анализ трафика. например выдача кук при первом посещении с данного ip и если он опять через короткое время пришел без куки - то ошибка. Наиболее настойчивых можно автоматом добавлять в фаервол и блокировать трафик.